# WordPress TinyMCE : Get value of popup button

Tags: shortcode

I'm developing a shortcode plugin, with a main button and sub-menu buttons for each shortcode, I create bootstrap thumbnail shortcode with a popup button for parameters like :

- Thumbnail Title
- Insert Image
- Button Link
- Button Color

In the Button Color I make it like this :

```
    {
     type: 'button',
     name: 'thumbbtncolor',
     label: 'Button Color',
     text: 'Choose Button Color',
     onclick: function() {
            editor.windowManager.open( {
                  title: 'Insert Button Color',
                  body: [
                        {
                          type   : 'colorpicker',
                         }]
            });
    }
}
```

So, when I click on it a popup window with color picker show, and here's the problem, I want to get the value of colorpicker (selected color ) and inserted in a text box field :

```
{
type: 'textbox',
name: 'thumbbtnclass',
label: 'Button Color Value'
}
```